# CLLocationManager.requestLocation how long does it take to call its delegates

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

We received a report where some users were stuck in certain screen of our app and can't proceed to the app's dashboard.

Upon checking the screen in question, it's a "loading" screen which will be displayed after the user successfully logged in. The only code that may cause the user to stuck here is the CLLocationManager. The screen will wait for the CLLocationManager to call the didUpdateLocations or didFailWithError then proceed to the app's dashboard.

My guess is the CLLocationManage didn't call any of its delegates. Thus the user was stuck in the "loading" screen.

How long does the CLLocationManager.requestLocation call its delegate functions? If the request takes too long does the CCLocationManager call the didFailWithError?

Below is shorten version of our codes:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    // process the location then forward to dashboard screen
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    // forward to dashboard screen
}
```

Any information is very much appreciated! TIA!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `startUpdatingLocation()` it usually takes around one second to get the first update. The first update is often an old (cached) location but it will arrive quickly.

Using `requestLocation()` might take a few seconds longer because it will wait until it has a single good location.

> This method returns immediately. Calling it causes the location manager to obtain a location fix (**which may take several seconds**) and call the delegate’s locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:) method with the result. The location fix is obtained at the accuracy level indicated by the desiredAccuracy property. Only one location fix is reported to the delegate, after which location services are stopped.

Your problem is that you didn't call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` on your location manager. You have to ask for permission to use location. There are some other things you need to do as well as calling that function (add keys to the app's Info.plist).

Comment: we already asked for requestWhenInUseAuthorization() in the login screen and the user has accepted it. The Info.plist also contains the required keys.

Comment: @SquareBox I can only debug the code I can see. The answer to your question "How long does the CLLocationManager.requestLocation call its delegate functions?" is "usually within one second or several seconds if you use `requestLocation`". If it fails you should get an error through the delegate method.